# Retrieving specific characters from string separated by a delimiter

Tags: c#, string, delimiter

I want to retrieve characters separated by a specific delimiter.

Example :

Here, I want to access the string between the " " delimiters. But I want the 2nd set of characters between "".

```
abc"def"ghi"jklm // Output : ghi

"hello" yes "world" // output : world
```

How can I get that?
I know we can use split. But sometimes the string might not start with " character.

Can anyone please help me with this?

Comment: It seems there's no pattern. If ghi for 1st, then it's b/w 2nd and 3rd quotes. If world for the 2nd, it's b/w 3rd and 4th quote. Doesn't seem clear what "2nd set of characters" means.

Comment: if only a single quote is the delimiter, the 2nd output should be " yes " according to ' But I want the 2nd set of characters'

Comment: Even in the first line, the second value is `def`, not `ghi`. What you ask would make sense if you wanted the *third* set of characters

Comment: No, ghi makes sense, it's the 2nd set within quotes. abc is not within, so def is the first.

Comment: I want 2nd set of characters with the quote. For first line ghi is within the quotes. For the second line world is within the quote.

Comment: No, "yes" is within quotes, just like "ghi".

Comment: hello is in the quote and then world is in the quote. yes is NOT

Answer (score 0):

```
string valueStr = "abc\"def\"ghi\"jklm";
var result = valueStr.Split('"')[2];
Console.WriteLine(result);
```

https://dotnetfiddle.net/T3fMof

Obviously check for the array elements before accessing them

Comment: This passes the first example, but fails the second one.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but in 2nd output, this would return 'yes', not what OP said is needed, 'world'.

Comment: Now your fiddle is right, but not the output requested.

Comment: yes if you want the 2nd set then it will display "yes". As you mentioned before and I agree with you his pattern doesnt match...unless I'm missing the point here

Comment: Actually your answer almost works, but will return the *third* string *not* second string.

Answer (score 0):

You can just find the first quote, and use your approach from there:

```
var firstQuote = str.IndexOf('"');

var startsWithQuote = str.Substring(firstQuote);
```

Comment: What approach? OP did not have an approach.

Comment: The OP described his problem as sometimes not having the " as the first character in the string, thus using string.Split() would do different things for him. Thus I provided him with a way to trim the characters before the "

Answer (score 0):

You can use regular expressions to match them:

```
        var test = "abc\"def\"ghi\"jklm";
        var test2 = "\"hello\" yes \"world\"";

        var match1 = Regex.Matches(test, ".+\"(.+)\"");
        var match2 = Regex.Matches(test2, ".+\"(.+)\"");

        Console.WriteLine("Match1: " + match1[0].Groups[1].Captures[0]);
        Console.WriteLine("Match2: " + match2[0].Groups[1].Captures[0]);
        // Match1: ghi
        // Match2: world
```